# Angular Material Menu module: Export of name 'matMenu' not found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I have a little issue with Angular Material Menu module.

I have this code in my **app.module.ts**:

```js
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my **shared.module.ts**:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { ListDropdownComponent } from './list-dropdown/list-dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ListDropdownComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatMenuModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    ListDropdownComponent,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

In my **list-dropdown.component.ts**:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './list-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class ListDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

In the **list-dropdown.component.html**:

```html
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  My dropdown menu
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-menu>
```

Then I have this error message:

```
Error: Export of name 'matMenu' not found!
```

I can't see where is the problem here?

Comment: You probably need to restart `ng serve`

Comment: is it require BrowserAnimationsModule?

Comment: thanks @PoulKruijt , the restart helped.

Comment: thanks bro it helped

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem and a server restart fixed it.

Comment: You should have just upvote / post "thank you" for a comment by @Poul Kruijt :)

Comment: I tried many things and this strangely resolved my issue ? Usually the application gets into this state when I generate something , or npm install a new package ... still want to understand root cause.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem executing the **unit tests**.

**Solved** by importing MatMenuModule to the TestBed:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MatMenuModule],
      declarations: [YOURCOMPONENT],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem -
close your terminal and again start server (ng serve).

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem today and what you need to do is just import this line below in the current component's module you using matMenu
`import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';`

Answer (score 1):

For me, just restarting `ng serve` wasn't enough. I didn't get rid of the error, until I removed the `mat-menu` directives from the template, restarted `ng serve`, and then simply added the `mat-menu` stuff back to the template. Crazy error!

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue while unit testing, but after importing **MatMenuModule**
in spec file, fixed this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and restarting the server just worked for me!